# session variable only retrieves the previous value

Tags: php, session

I need to get a session variable value and compare it with an input.

here is the code:

```
<?php
echo "<img src='captchas.php'><br><center><input type='text' size='10' name='check' id='postcaptcha' onChange='validatecaptcha();'></center><div id='validationforcaptcha'></div>";

$captchacode = $_SESSION['newcode'];

echo "<input type='text' name='sessioncaptcha' id='sessioncaptcha' value=$captchacode />"; 
?>
```

and here is the captcha.php

```
    <?php session_start(); ob_start();

$img = imagecreatefrompng('IMAGES/black.png'); 
$numero = rand(100000000, 999999999); 
$_SESSION['check23'] = $numero;
$white = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 255, 255); 
imagestring($img, 10, 8, 3, $numero, $white); 

header ("Content-type: image/png"); 
imagepng($img); 

?>
```

i don't know why the $_SESSION['check23'] variable only retrieves the previous captcha code that has been displayed (not what is currently displayed)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you're assuming that your first script gets executed **after** *captcha.php*?

This is what's actually happening:

1. Your first script is executed and the page is served to the user.
2. The user's browser requests *captcha.php* as an image.
3. *captcha.php* is executed and the image is sent to the user.

Try generating the CAPTCHA code in the first script and saving it to `$_SESSION['check23']`. You can retrieve `$_SESSION['check23']` later in *captcha.php* to render the appropriate image.